# : "Cannot set property 'user' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, express-session

Im getting an error when i try to set a session once user has been created: "Cannot set property 'user' of undefined".

```
 exports.signUp=function(req,res){  // singup
        new user({                  //user model
            username: req.body.username, // req body
             }).save(function(error,user){ //After a successful save of user
               **req.session.user=user.id;**  // here is the error after a successful save
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you used a middleware something like this in your node app?

```
app.use(session({
secret: 'botnyuserdetails', // session secret
resave: true,
saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Comment: i set it in the server.js as below.
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost/my_database';

mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useMongoClient: true
});

var db = mongoose.connection;


    var expressSession=require('express-session');
    var mongoStore=require('connect-mongo') ({session:expressSession});

    app.use(expressSession({
        secret:'SECRET',
        cookie:{maxAge:60*60*1000},
        store:new mongoStore({
            db:db.db,
            collection:'sessions'
        })
    }));

Comment: could you post a code of app ,sometimes it is the order of using middlewares that makes the trouble

Comment: actually i didnt define anything in app.js ,  created a server and databse connection in server.js. but i have instance of app.js in server then i set express session

Comment: app = require('./app')('express')
 
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost/my_database';
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
  useMongoClient: true
});

var db = mongoose.connection;


    var expressSession=require('express-session');
    var mongoStore=require('connect-mongo') ({session:expressSession});

    app.use(expressSession({
        secret:'SECRET',
        cookie:{maxAge:60*60*1000},
        store:new mongoStore({
            db:db.db,
            collection:'sessions'
        })
    }));

});

Comment: Post the code in your question description for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.signUp=function(req,res){  // singup
        new user({                  //user model
            username: req.body.username, // req body
             }).save(function(error){ 
               //**req.session.user=user.id;**
               // save function doesn't return user
               // you can use this approach
               if(error){
                 res.json({error:"cannot save"})
               }
               else{
                 req.session.user = req.body.username;
               }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It doesnt work out, actually i am receiviing user from save , the problem with req.session but not sure the fix